# Кабсдох - происхождение слова

Tags: этимология

Недавно увидела интересное слово - кабсдох (собака). Откуда это слово взялось? Какой-то жаргон? Или диалект?

Comment: "да чтоб ты сдох" - это понятно. Но почему это означает собака? Почему, скажем, не таракан? Или заклятый враг? У этого слова есть определенный автор или оно народное? Пока самая правдоподобная версия - литературное происхождение. @DocentI, преобразуйте Ваш комментарий в ответ, у него все шансы быть принятым. Есть другие версии?

Answer (score 3):

Теперь, видимо, и не узнать, что от чего произошло.Кличка собаки, скорее всего, от возгласа, а потом эта кличка стала нарицательным именем для всех беспородных животных.
У Н. Заболоцкого есть стихотворение - пародия о Кабысдохе: http://www.lib.ru/ANEKDOTY/parnas.txt_with-big-pictures.html
Пародия была написана в 1930 году, а это прозвище для собак и вообще для всяких беспородных неприглядных животных-доходяг использовалось и раньше, особенно на юге, в Одессе, например. Видимо,Н. Заболоцкий взял слово в народной среде, где оно ходит наравне с"псиной", шариком, полканом (как нарицательное). 
Сейчас используется в сканвордах и просто в разговоре как нарицательное: КАБЫСДОХ - Ненавистная псина (разг.) http://bjik.ru/cgi-bin/scanword.pl?g=2010&n=56&p=odnoklassniki

Например: . "Он чмокал, цыкал, дергал веревочными вожжами пару разномастных, никогда не чищенных «кабысдохов», из тех, о которых популярный в то время певец Паша Богатырев пел в концертах слезный романс… В. А. Гиляровский, «Москва и москвичи», 1934 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы) ◆ Да, впрочем, шпак не один прибежал, выкатилась целая орава дворняжек, все эти трезорки, бутоны, кабысдохи, милки и ремзочки, и та, что вовсе без имени. Георгий Владимов, «Верный Руслан», 1965 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка);

...каждый бомж обшаривает помойные баки при аккомпанементе не менее пяти кабысдохов... Да собачонка-то, кабысдох безродный. ... Серый и очень грязный кабысдох сидел на дороге и ждал меня.

Comment: Только не пародия Заболоцкого, а пародия *на* Заболоцкого, созданная одним из авторов "Парнаса дыбом". О чем я уже упоминала

Answer (score 1):

Так обычно называют собаку-доходягу:)))

Comment: Я видела кличку Кабысдох в сборнике "Парнас дыбом", в разделе о попе и его собаке. Думаете, они взяли известную кличку? Не сами придумали?

Comment: Да это популярная кличка собак наряду с Полканом и Шариком. Хотя, мягко скажем, не гуманная.

Comment: Не  обязательно  собаку  так  называли. Прозвище  могло  относится  к  старому  и  нелюбимому  мужу.  Источник " Русская  народная  сатира".  Но  точную  ссылку  дать  не  могу,  не  помню.

Comment: "У нас в городе при складе есть собака, так ту зовут Кабысдох" Чехов, "Иванов". 

Явно не новое.

>Но точную ссылку дать не могу, не помню  
  
Жаль. Версия интуитивно очень правдоподобная.